# Получить дату и время в unix time

Tags: php, дата, время, unixtimestamp

Есть дата и время, например `08.06.2013 15:40`.

Как средствами PHP получить unix time этой даты?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$date = '2016-05-24 16:32:45';
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться функцией `getTimestamp` ([документация](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.gettimestamp.php))

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/173833)

Comment: @retorta во первых это преобразованный кем то коммент в ответ, во вторых иногда ссылка на официальную документацию гораздо лучше готового решения.

Comment: @zb', такое бывает. Если вас не затруднит, добавьте хотя бы какое-то описание, типа "Нужно воспользоваться методом/функцией/etc."

Comment: @insolor сложно, я с мобилки, если не хватает репутации, рекомендуйте исправление, я одобрю

Comment: Пока так. Хорошо бы еще кто-то добавил пример использования, а то я в PHP не разбираюсь.

Comment: @retorta, имени функции достаточно для ответа.

Comment: @Qwertiy, до моей правки была только ссылка.

Answer (score 0):

Вернее так надо поступать:

```
$date = '2016-05-24 16:32:45';

$timestamp = strtotime($date);
```

в приведенном выше примере допущена ошибка, вместо `strtotime($date)` указан вызов функции `strtotime()` без переменной `$date`.

Comment: Я отредактировал приведенный выше пример. Вот так надо поступать.